# yet another question about python continuations

Tags: python, lambda, fibonacci, continuations, cps

all
trying to work out how continuations work in python.
i have the following code to calculate fibonacci using a python cps implementation ( i realize that it is building a stack, but for this question i am hoping this code will be sufficient ).

```
def fact_cps(n, k):
    print("n:%s" %(n))
    if n == 1:
        return k(1)
    else:
        return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
```

My question is:

- in the output below, the lambda variable "v" attains a value of 1
- this occurs as a result of the previous function returning k(1)
- SO: what is the mechanism by which "v=1" happens?

Not sure if this is my lack of understanding of lambda's specifically in python or in general.

Execution with trace:

```
python2 -m pdb python-cps-fact.py  < in > out
```

"in" is a file containing repeated "s" and "a" debug inputs to step/display variables repeatedly

```
s
a
....
```

In the "out" file below, i have indicated the spot for my question by bounding it with a line of asterisks.

"out" is the output for the trace:

```
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(1)<module>()
-> def fact_cps(n, k):
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(8)<module>()
-> if __name__ == "__main__":
(Pdb) (Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(9)<module>()
-> print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
(Pdb) (Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(1)fact_cps()
-> def fact_cps(n, k):
(Pdb) n = 3
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3aa0>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(2)fact_cps()
-> print("n:%s" %(n))
(Pdb) n = 3
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3aa0>
(Pdb) n:3
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(3)fact_cps()
-> if n == 1:
(Pdb) n = 3
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3aa0>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)fact_cps()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) n = 3
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3aa0>
(Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(1)fact_cps()
-> def fact_cps(n, k):
(Pdb) n = 2
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3ed8>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(2)fact_cps()
-> print("n:%s" %(n))
(Pdb) n = 2
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3ed8>
(Pdb) n:2
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(3)fact_cps()
-> if n == 1:
(Pdb) n = 2
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3ed8>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)fact_cps()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) n = 2
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3ed8>
(Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(1)fact_cps()
-> def fact_cps(n, k):
(Pdb) n = 1
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3d70>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(2)fact_cps()
-> print("n:%s" %(n))
(Pdb) n = 1
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3d70>
(Pdb) n:1
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(3)fact_cps()
-> if n == 1:
(Pdb) n = 1
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3d70>
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(4)fact_cps()
-> return k(1)
(Pdb) n = 1
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3d70>
*************************************** HERE
(Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 1
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 1
************************************************************
(Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 2
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 2
(Pdb) --Call--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(9)<lambda>()
-> print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
(Pdb) i = 6
(Pdb) > /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(9)<lambda>()
-> print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
(Pdb) i = 6
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(9)<lambda>()->6
-> print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
(Pdb) i = 6
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()->6
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 2
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)<lambda>()->6
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) v = 1
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(4)fact_cps()->6
-> return k(1)
(Pdb) n = 1
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3d70>
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)fact_cps()->6
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) n = 2
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3ed8>
(Pdb) --Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(6)fact_cps()->6
-> return fact_cps(n - 1, lambda v: k(v * n) )
(Pdb) n = 3
k = <function <lambda> at 0x7fd438fe3aa0>
(Pdb) 6
--Return--
> /home/mrostron/work/prolog/python-cps-fact.py(9)<module>()->None
-> print(fact_cps(3, (lambda i : i)))
(Pdb) (Pdb) --Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
```

thanks v much for your time on this
mr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what your question is.  But the definition of your function `fact_cps(n, k)` is that it returns `k(n!)`.

- If n = 1, then it just calls k(1) directly.
- If n > 1, then it calls `fact_cps(n, xxx)`, where xxx is a function that multiplies the return result by `n`, and then calls `k` on that new value.  The recursive call will return n * (n - 1)! = n!, and then we call `k` on that.

The net result is that each call of `fact_cps` with n > 1 calls `fact_cps` with a smaller value of `n`, and the final result is `k(n!)`.  Your outer call sets k to be the identity function, so you get n!

---

Based on the comments you've made below, I'm starting to believe that you don't completely understand what a lambda function is.  A lambda lets you write a quick function without naming it.

Your code behaves exactly as if you had written:

```
def fact_cps(n, k):
    print("n:%s" %(n))
    if n == 1:
        return k(1)
    else:
        def inner(v):
            return k(v * n)
        return fact_cps(n - 1, inner)

def identity(i):
    return i

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(fact_cps(3, identity)
```

Perhaps this will help you see where the `v` is coming from

Comment: i think the bit dont understand is the jump from "lambda v: k(v*n)" to "multiplies the return result by n". from what you saying, is "v" is the return result? how does this work?

Comment: What does lambda v: k(v * n) mean?  It means 1) take the argument I've been given, multiply it by n, and then call k on it.   You are trying to do a proof by induction.  You need to prove that `fact_cps(n, k) = k(n!)` by induction.  Prove it for k=1.  (Obvious by defn.). Assume it is true for `k-1` and prove that it is also true for `k`.

Comment: thnx, but still stuck.

Comment: in the trace, the call to fact_cps(1, ....) returns k(1)
then, the trace indicates that v=1, and the return performs the remaining n! multiplication.
i dont see how the lambda argument "v" is assigned anywhere.
i am not sure if python is inferring that v=1 from the previous return of k(1)?

Answer (score 0):

PS my initial thought is that python is equating "k(1)" with "lambda v: k(v*n)" and the resulting value for "v" is obtained by inferring that the value (1) is equal to (v*n), and applying the value n=1, result t/f is v=1.

but i dont believe this is what is happening, and there is something that i am not seeing here.